# don't know how to use IShellWindows::Item correctly

Tags: c++, windows, com, windows-shell, visual-c++-6

I'm using VC6 on XP system.

The following is my code. It runs perfectly on my computer, but on other computers it seems that  pisw->Item(v, &pidisp) doesn't equals to S_OK. Now I'm trying to figure out what's wrong here

```
  IShellWindows *pisw;
  if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,
                             IID_IShellWindows, (void**)&pisw))) {
  VARIANT v;
  V_VT(&v) = VT_I4;
  IDispatch  *pidisp;
  found = FALSE;

  for (V_I4(&v) = 0; !found && pisw->Item(v, &pidisp) == S_OK; V_I4(&v)++) {
     IWebBrowserApp *piwba;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pidisp->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowserApp, (void**)&piwba))) {
               //  blablabla....do something..
  }
```

So I changed some code to

```
...
IDispatch *pidisp;
hr = pisw->Item(v, &pidisp);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
      for (V_I4(&v) = 0; !found ; V_I4(&v)++) {
     IWebBrowserApp *piwba;
     if (SUCCEEDED(pidisp->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowserApp, (void**)&piwba))) {
               //  blablabla....do something..
   }
```

}

then the return value of hr becomes to 1. And it gets access violation errors when running to "pidisp->.." step. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code incorrectly tests the result of `pisw->Item(v, &pidisp)`. Weird, because it does use the correct check later on.

The problem is that there are many success return values besides `S_OK`. Your fix is correct, you should use `SUCCEEDED(hr)`, but you incorrectly moved the loop INSIDE the `SUCCEEDED(hr)` test. You should check `SUCCEEDED(hr)` for every value of `V_I4(&v)`.

Your `S_FALSE` result is because you now call `hr = pisw->Item(v, &pidisp);` before the loop, which means `v` is uninitialized (garbage). Assume for a moment that its garbage value is 728365. `S_FALSE` means: the call succeeded, but there are less than 728365 windows.

Comment: Your answer explains a lot! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

MSDN [`IShellWindows::Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc836571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Return value Type: HRESULT S_FALSE (1) The specified window was not
>   found.

The item you are looking was not found, and you obviously don't get a valid `pidisp`. Trying to use it results - expectedly - in access violation.

You need to handle "item not found" case properly, and check your `v` argument as well.

Comment: I don't understand. I opened 3 or 4 shell windows. How come the specified window was not found??? And why putting pisw->Item(v, &pidisp) into the for statement is OK but adding a hr becomes wrong?

Comment: Besides, on another computer, pisw->Item(v, &pidisp) doesn't equals to S_OK so it doesn't run the following for statements. How can I solve that??

Comment: `Item` call finds nothing for given `v`. This is what is taking place. Returned value of `1` = `S_FALSE` is the indication of this case for you. This value still passes `SUCCEEDED` check and is not an error.

Comment: So how to give "v" a value??

Comment: And does item() function specify a window?? I didn't give it a parameter to specify which window...