# IShellWindows::get_Count doesn't get correct number of windows shells

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm using VC6 on XP system. The following code runs perfectly, no errors, no bugs. But it doesn't get the right number of windows shells! The return value of hr is 0, which is S_OK. I'm so confused! I opened only one windows shell, but lCount gets 5. I opened 3 windows shell, lCount gets 7. Can anyone give me a hint here?

```
IShellWindows *pisw = NULL;  
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellWindows, (void**)&psw);  

long lCount = 0;  
hr = pisw->get_Count(&lCount);
```

Comment: From the doc: "The Shell windows collection includes file explorer windows and web browser windows Internet Explorer and 3rd-party web browsers)". If you get a base number of 4, plus 1 per "shell" window you are opening by yourself (4+1=5, 4+3=7), it certainly means the OS does count some windows you did not count by yourself. This may be a problem for your specific goal (which is ...?) - it is e.g. *not* a reliable way to count what you call "shells".

Comment: @Tibo But I didn't open anything. No web browser or 3rd party web browsers at all. My goal is to find a windows explorer shell window. This is really strange. The same code works perfectly on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

The result *is* correct, it's the range of valid indices for `IShellWindows::Item(index)`

Comment: But I didn't open anything. No web browser or 3rd party web browsers at all. My goal is to find a windows explorer shell window. I only opened 2 or 3 windows explorer windows. On another computer, it works fine. The lCount gets the right number of open explorer windows. And what do you mean by ::Item(index)??

Comment: So? If the count returned is 7, that means `IShellWindows::Item` will give you back 7 different values if you call it with 7 different indices.

Comment: do you know how to use IShellWindows::Item?? I have another code which is wrong and I really don't know how to fix it!! Please help! here is the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183359/dont-know-how-to-use-ishellwindowsitem-correctly

Comment: do you know how to use IShellWindows::Item?? I have another code which is wrong and I really don't know how to fix it!! Please help! here is the post:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183359/dont-know-how-to-use-ishellwindowsitem-correctly

Comment: yeah, that's also a bit of a mess. COM can be hard for beginners.